How To Escape Double Quotes in MSHTA JavaScript
Batch Script:
@echo off
set "shell=new ActiveXObject('shell.application').ShellExecute"
:: Worked
set "arg1=cmd.exe"& set "arg2=/k title Command Prompt"
set "arg1=cmd.exe"& set "arg2=/c C:\\Temp\\test4.bat"
set "arg1=wt.exe"&  set "arg2=-p PowerShell"
:: Not Worked
::set "arg1=cmd.exe"& set "arg2=/c ^"C:\\Temp\\test 4.bat^""
::set "arg1=wt.exe"& set "arg2=-p ^"Command Prompt^" cmd.exe"
MSHTA "javascript: %shell%('%arg1%', '%arg2%', '', 'runas', 1); close();"

I don't know the correct writing format when arg2 contains spaces or is enclosed in double quotes.
These not worked:
set "arg1=cmd.exe"& set "arg2=/c ^"C:\\Temp\\test 4.bat^""
set "arg1=cmd.exe"& set "arg2=/c start \"Command Prompt\""
set "arg1=wt.exe"& set "arg2=-p ^"Command Prompt^" cmd.exe"
-p \"Command Prompt\" cmd.exe
-p ""Command Prompt""

How should the correct writing format be?

Why modify them at the set command, so they undergo an additional parsing stage?

Like this "arg2=/c \"C:\\Temp\\test 4.bat\""

@mplungjan I tried set "arg2=-p \"Command Prompt\" cmd.exe", not worked

To expand upon my previous comment. You are first escaping for the set command; what is being passed as the content of the variable may not be what you think it is. Try first of all using Set arg to see their actual string data before trying to use them.

In Javascript, the syntax for "C:\Temp\test 4.bat" is "C:\\Temp\\test 4.bat", and use "\..\" to escape double-quotes inside quotes.
So, becomes \""C:\\Temp\\test 4.bat"\"
@echo off
set "shell=new ActiveXObject('shell.application').ShellExecute"
set "arg1=cmd.exe"& set "arg2=/c \""C:\\Temp\\test 4.bat"\""
MSHTA "javascript: %shell%('%arg1%', '%arg2%', '', 'runas', 1); close();"
::exit /b
:: manually
:: MSHTA "javascript: %shell%('cmd.exe', '/c \""C:\\Temp\\test 4.bat"\"', '', 'runas', 1); close();"
:: MSHTA "javascript: %shell%('\""C:\\Temp\\test 4.bat"\"', '', '', 'runas', 1); close();"

I've tested for other option, like set "arg1=cmd.exe"& set arg2=/c start \""Command Prompt"\", but don't worked.
Perhaps someone will help u in other answer.
